# What part of speech is 'soaking' in 'soaking wet'?

Tags: parts-of-speech

In the sentence, "I am soaking wet", 'I' is the noun, 'am' is the verb, 'wet' is the adjective, and 'soaking' describes the extent of 'wet'. So would 'soaking' be classified as a "helping adjective", so to speak? Or just an adjective? Or is there a better term to describe this?

Comment: If you require that the modifier of an adjective be an adverb, then, since _wet_ is an adjective modified by _soaking_, you could call it an adverb. Or you could call it a quantifier. Or you could call it an intensifier. Or you could just call it another adjective, part of a fixed idiomatic phrase _soaking wet_. It's not terribly important what name you use; nobody cares and nobody agrees anyway.

Comment: "Soaking" derives from the participle of the verb "soak", and is used here as an adjective (a participial adjective, to be precise) to modify "wet".

Comment: Up-voted. A good question which brought forth a good answer (comment) from Professor Lawler.

Comment: @BillJ If *soaking* is an adjective, wouldn’t that imply that *wet* is a noun here? I know you can go out in the wet, where it’s a noun; Dickens wrote “Make haste in out of the wet, Tom.”  But I would have thought it a predicate adjective in the sample sentence.

Comment: @tchrist see [link](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/learner-english/soaking)

Comment: @BillJ Was the link to your own user actually what you intended there?

Comment: @tchrist I don't follow you.

Comment: @BillJ Somehow I clicked on you not the link. :) But I don't understand that analysis.

Comment: @BillJ The OED calls *soaking* “quasi-*adv*” in *soaking wet*. Which probably isn't getting us any closer to anything.

Answer (score 5):

One can be *barely, slightly, moderately, soaking,* and *dripping* wet, all describing a degree of wetness. As the *-ly* suffixes on the first three in the list suggest, this is the task of adverbs, even if by form, *soaking* and *dripping* are [present participles](https://www.englishpractice.com/grammar/participle/) without verbal force.

This is hardly an unusual construction: *burning/scorching/piping hot, freezing cold, raving/barking mad*, but *deafeningly loud, exceedingly hungry*.

Comment: Hmmm, were we in a sane world, we would spell the adverb as "soakingly". I like that your answer kind'a shows that.

Comment: @thorr18 Why? We don't spell adverbs *soonly* or *oftenly* or *fastly* or *therely*. The modernist -ly obsession is unhistorical. Present particles can be adverbs without cumbersome decorations.

Comment: I am unaware of any obsession with ly. My opinion was just based on a feeling, not a trend.

Comment: Also, I wouldn't feel it looked weird if people spelled it with a hyphen. I would have the same feeling with fast-wet and fastly wet, were that a thing.

Comment: After years of getting rid of excess hyphens they're now turning up in all sorts of inappropriate places. Tossing one between an adverb and the adjective it modifies makes no sense, though Chicago now demands _a bright-blue dress_ for some reason.

Comment: It's a verb, so using it as an adverb creates a hiccup in my read, due to syntax. Without ly, the two words are actually combined to function as a single part of speech - an adjective. I don't prefer the hyphen over using ly but it explicitly shows what you are doing. If soaking were a participle, it would modify a noun or verb. I don't think of wet as a noun. It can be a verb (I wet the canvas) but then are we modifying a verb with a verb? It still doesn't make sense unless the tenses match. It'd be "soaking *and* wet", were they adjectives.

Comment: It's a _verbal_, not a verb, and regardless of what you sense is the illogic of it all, _piping hot_ and _soaking wet_ are highly idiomatic and the two -ing forms function as adverbs of degree. Others take an -ly suffix, but not these.